# OpenGl - texture glutSolidSphere?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, glut

How can I apply a texture to a glutSolidSphere?

this what i have tried but it doesn't work:

```
GLuint textureid;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureid);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, "stone.tga");
// Planet
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);
    glutSolidSphere(35.0f, 30, 17);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

can some one direct me on how to Load the texture and enable it.

i heard that glutSolidSphere emits texture coordinates already, so i don't have to do anything special there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not actually creating a texture with `glTexImage2D`. The last parameter should be a `byte[]` of pixel channel colors in the order Red, Green, Blue, Alpha (as specified by your other parameters - `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_RGBA`), and not just the name of the file.

OpenGL has no clue what a file is, how to read a file from a system-specific filesystem, or how to parse the TGA file format. It's expecting raw color data, so you need to load and parse your image and pass the `byte[]` to OpenGL (technically the pointer to the first element as a `void*`). There are [several](http://thatotherdev.com/2010/11/07/loading-tga-files-in-c-for-use-with-opengl/) [guides](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/396820) that give you the minimum code necessary to parse a TGA file, but you can also use a library like [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) to handle loading your textures, and it works with much more than just TGA.

Comment: thanks for ur reply Robert i think i understand what ur saying but its gonna be a while till i fully understand it

Comment: It's fairly simple if you break it down to the very basics. Colors (at least in computers) are represented by a mix of 3 colors: Red, Green, and Blue. (There's also transparency: Alpha). File formats like TGA aren't just a `byte[]` array full of the color values of each pixel, there are file headers, compression, etc. What you need to do is strip away all the excess from your TGA texture to retrieve the raw image data. You then just send that raw data to OpenGL and it handles it from there.

Comment: if u could actually show me it would be too good to be true :p ... but anyways thanks for ur help so far  Robert i appreciate it

Comment: The two guides I linked to (I'll link to them here again: [1](http://thatotherdev.com/2010/11/07/loading-tga-files-in-c-for-use-with-opengl/), [2](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/396820)) provide code you can basically drop in to your code to make it work.

Comment: thanks man u know on link 2 whats "rb" on this line
{file = fopen(filename, "rb");}

Comment: It's a parameter for `fopen`, if you look at the documentation for it you'll notice that it means read-only and in binary mode. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/